# Not Found error after logging in with google using django-allauth

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-authentication, django-allauth

I am using django-allauth package and google provider for authentication in my django project. Everything worked fine in development however when I launched my project on the server, I got an error. When I press the "Log in with Google" button in my sign in page, I get redirected to the page where google asks me to [choose my Google account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Gyr.png) to continue with.

Then after this step, where I get redirected to my site, I'm encountered with a [Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw7lK.png) error.

I tried a bunch of stuff found online but they didn't work.

here is my [Google credentials authorized redirect URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qJtJ.png).

In my settings.py file I configured allauth as below:

```
# Django-allauth configs

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.User'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

SITE_ID = 1

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_USER_MODEL_USERNAME_FIELD = None

ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_REDIRECT_URL = 'accounts:create_profile_url'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'dashboard_url'

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'login': 'accounts.forms.CustomLoginForm',
    'signup': 'accounts.forms.CustomSignupForm',
    'change_password': 'accounts.forms.CustomChangePasswordForm',
}

ACCOUNT_DEFAULT_HTTP_PROTOCOL='https'
```

and I've added 'allauth.urls' in my urlpatterns too

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

I could really use some help. Thanks.

Comment: are you running this is localhost?

Comment: Please check redirected url. It seems like it is redirected to different domain.

Comment: @Sumithran No this is on a hosting service

Comment: @PrabinSapal You mean in my Google console settings?